# anvil baking problem

Tags: modeling, baking

[image: god forsaken horn]
Im posting this cuz I dont have any more ideas and I really want to go on
Anvil tutorial was going pretty well for me before baking stage, simply cannot find settings on which there are no intersections and this god forsaken horn doesnt look like its made of origami
Please guys, just tell me the settings and Ill be forever grateful to you
blend file in the link:
https://we.tl/t-x41HXwhb52

Comment: You have not UV Unwrapped your anvils.  For baking to work, both anvils need to be UV unwrapped.  Go back to the tutorial and do the section where he shows how to unwrap them.

Comment: thanks man, i somehow missed it

Comment: no problem.  One of the problems with most tutorials is that the authors can't remember all of the mistakes people might make so they rarely have good "and if it didn't work try this" sections.  The best you can do is go back to the tutorial and make sure you really have done everything the same way.